# Uncaught (in promise) Error: No ethereum object at sendTransaction (TransactionContext.jsx:105:13)

Tags: javascript, try-catch, ethereum, solidity, metamask

In TransactionContext.js (see code below), I am getting a no ethereum object error in the connectWallet function whenever i submit data to the ethereum blockchain. However, I have already connected metamask to the website. There should be an ethereum object. How do i resolve this error?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y9X4.jpg)
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ABUn.jpg)

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {ethers} from 'ethers'
import { contractABI, contractAddress } from "../utils/constants"
export const TransactionContext = React.createContext()

const { ethereum } = window;

const createEthereumContract = () => {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
  const signer = provider.getSigner();
  const transactionsContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer);

  return transactionsContract;
};

//have to also create our context because where are we going to call this - we need to have a
//specific place where it's going to serve a purpose for that reason

//function to check if a wallet is connected at the start
export const TransactionProvider = ({children}) => {
  
  const [formData, setformData] = useState({ addressTo: "", amount: "", keyword: "", message: "" });
  const [currentAccount, setCurrentAccount] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [transactionCount, setTransactionCount] = useState(localStorage.getItem("transactionCount"));
  const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState([]);
  
  //handleChange func interact with inputs except the event
  const handleChange = (e, name) => {
    setformData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: e.target.value }));
  };

  const getAllTransactions = async () =>{
    //check if browser has metamask installed
    try {if(!ethereum) return alert("Please install metamask")

    const transactionContract = createEthereumContract();
    const availableTransactions = await transactionContract.getAllTransactions()
    
    //change structure of data 
    const structuredTransactions = availableTransactions.map((transaction)=>({
      addressTo: transaction.receiver,
      addressFrom: transaction.sender,
      timestamp: new Date(transaction.timestamp.toNumber() * 1000).toLocaleString(),
      message: transaction.message,
      keyword: transaction.keyword,
      amount: parseInt(transaction.amount._hex) / (10 ** 18)
    }))

    } catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  const checkIfWalletIsConnected = async() =>{
    try{
      if(!ethereum) return alert("Please install metamask")
      const accounts = await ethereum.request({method:'eth_accounts'})
      console.log(accounts)

      if(accounts.length){
        setCurrentAccount(accounts[0])

        getALLtransactions()
      } else {
        console.log('No accounts found')
      }
    } catch(error){
      console.log(error)
      throw new Error("No ethereum object")
    }
  }

const checkIfTransactionsExist = async () => {
  try {
    const transactionsContract = createEthereumContract()
    const transactionsCount = await transactionsContract.getTransactionCount()

    window.localStorage.setItem("transactionCount",transactionCount)
  } catch(error) {
  }
}

  {/*function for connecting the account */}
  const connectWallet = async () => {
    try {
      if (!ethereum) return alert("Please install MetaMask.");

      const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts", });

      setCurrentAccount(accounts[0]);
      window.location.reload();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);

      throw new Error("No ethereum object");
    }
  }

  const sendTransaction = async () => {
    try {
      if (ethereum) {
        const { addressTo, amount, keyword, message } = formData;
        const transactionsContract = createEthereumContract();
        const parsedAmount = ethers.utils.parseEther(amount);

        await ethereum.request({
          method: "eth_sendTransaction",
          params: [{
            from: currentAccount,
            to: addressTo,
            gas: "0x5208",
            value: parsedAmount._hex,
          }],
        });

        const transactionHash = await transactionsContract.addToBlockchain(addressTo, parsedAmount, message, keyword);

        setIsLoading(true);
        console.log(`Loading - ${transactionHash.hash}`);
        await transactionHash.wait();
        console.log(`Success - ${transactionHash.hash}`);
        setIsLoading(false);

        const transactionsCount = await   transactionsContract.getTransactionCount();

        setTransactionCount(transactionsCount.toNumber());
        window.location.reload();
      } else {
        console.log("No ethereum object");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);

      throw new Error("No ethereum object");
    }
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    checkIfWalletIsConnected()
    checkIfTransactionsExist()
  },[])

  return(
<TransactionContext.Provider value={{connectWallet, currentAccount,formData,handleChange,sendTransaction,transactions,isLoading}}>
  {children}
</TransactionContext.Provider>)}
```

Comment: so, what is the error logged before that throw, and you may get more better info if you `console.error(error)` rather than `console.log(error)`

Comment: In sendTransaction() Function, there is TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined ( reading 'Web3Provider') and Uncaught (in promise) Error: No ethereum object.

Comment: from the code you've shown, that suggests `ethers.providers` is undefined - at a guess,you're using ethers version 5.x (or earlier) methods/syntax but have ethers vesion 6.x installed

Comment: Thanks i changed from ```const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum); ``` to ```const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);``` and it worked